# tryCatch error: the action can´t be completed because the folder is open in RStudio R session

Tags: r, windows, session

When I download files (Windows 7) using

```
tryCatch(download.file(paste0(url_bv,arq), paste0(dir_bv,arq))
       ,error=function(cond) message(paste('erro:',arq,'não encontrado'))
       ,warning=function(cond) message(paste('warning:',arq,'não encontrado')))
```

I can´t delete files, getting the msg in the question title.

If I just do

```
download.file(paste0(url_bv,arq), paste0(dir_bv,arq))
```

there is no problem.

How can I release the folder/file in R?

Comment: Are you able to close or restart the R session within RStudio? Does `showConnections()` list anything active? If so try to close them.

Comment: @r2evans, just stdin, stdout and stderr. I can restart RStudio - it works fine. When I do, file is released.

Comment: Some time ago I found a package (`readr`, I believe) that was holding onto a file descriptor after some type of error, and a restart was the only remedy. Is it possible that the download "mostly" finished but not completely? Can you reproduce the behavior with the same download?

Comment: The file is quite small (150KB) and is written with 0 KB size when is not found on url. The behavior is consistent.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in R-3.2.5 on win10_64. What are the values of `url_bv`, `dir_bv`, and `arq`?

Comment: url_bv='http://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/fechamento-pregao/bdi/'; dir_bv, anywhere in your hd; arq='bdi0101.zip', e.g.. Tks @r2evans

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely a bug in R (windows version). I can faithfully reproduce it in R-3.2.5 (win10_64). I suggest you file a bug report (read [R FAQ 9.2](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-to-report-a-bug) for clear direction).

I tried it with several variations:

- different url schemes (`"http://"` and `"https://"`)
- different `download.file(..., method=...)` options (`"wininet"`, `"internal"`, and `"auto"` all behaved in this manner; `"libcurl"` did not, but it merely downloaded the `404.html` without telling me there was a problem)
- triggers whenever `warning=...` or `condition=...` clauses are given to `tryCatch` **and** something weird happens in `expr`
- does not trigger with `error=...` or `finally=...` arguments
- 32bit and 64bit variants
- *not* in RStudio
- as `R --vanilla`

All attempted on ubuntu-14.04 (R-3.2.3-64bit) as well, it would not trigger.